# Rails 4 - setting belongs_to relationship not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, belongs-to

I have two models, `Team` and `Plan`. Team has a one to many relationship with plans, where plans can have many teams and each team have one plan. It looks like this:

```
#Plan
has_many :teams

#Team
belongs_to :plan
```

I'm using [Stripe](https://www.stripe.com) for recurring billing, and I'm using `[webhooks][2]` to keep my app synced with Stripe. To receive Stripe events I'm using the gem `[stripe_event][3]`. When subscriptions are created I want to set the plan to the newly created subscription plan. When I get the Stripe event `customer.subscription.created` I do the following:

```
events.subscribe 'customer.subscription.created' do |event|
  team = Team.find_by_stripe_customer_id(event.data.object.customer)
  create_subscription_for_team(team, event.data.object)

  # In this methods I want to set my plan
  set_team_plan(team, event.data.object.plan)
end

def set_team_plan(team, plan)
  team_plan = Plan.find_by_stripe_id(plan.id)
  team.update_attribute(plan_id: team_plan.id)
end
```

I don't get any errors what I can see, but the plan don't seem to get updated. I have also tried:

```
team.plan = team_plan
team.save!
```

But this gives me the same result. When I have logged I have confirmed that `team_plan` is the correct plan, and is not nil.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the inverse relationships:

```
#Plan
has_many :teams, inverse_of: :plan

#Team
belongs_to :plan, inverse_of: teams
```

The inverse relationships help ensure that `save` works when you save subobjects.

Try looking at the id of each item before and after save:

```
p "team_plan.id:#{team_plan.id}, team.plan.id: #{team.plan.id}"
team.plan = team_plan
p "team_plan.id:#{team_plan.id}, team.plan.id:#{team.plan.id}"
team.save!
p "team_plan.id:#{team_plan.id}, team.plan.id:#{team.plan.id}"
```

If you're comfortable with Rails logger, or `pry`, or a debugger, use those instead of print statements. :)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I did try save! (not having the `!` was a type from he here, I have now updated my question). When setting `inverse_of` as you suggests I get this: `ActionView::Template::Error (Could not find the inverse association for plan (:team in Plan)):`

Comment: @Anders My typo -- use inverse_of :teams (plural)

Comment: Actually it was related to something else. In my `Team` model I had a `before_create` where I set a default `Plan`. This action got called also when my Plan gets created for some reason.